# Can't create mobile analytics experiment from GTM since migrating to GTM v2

Tags: android, ios, google-tag-manager, google-experiments

I migrated my google tag manager container to GTM v2 (android and iOS) a few weeks back. Since I did that I have not been able to setup any mobile analytics experiments.

I have connected the container to an analytics view and chosen a goal when creating the experiment.

Everything works until trying to publish the container. When publishing an error is displayed stating "The experiments contain unrecoverable errors."

I have tried to strip away as much as possible to figure out why it doesnt work, but still havn't figured it out.

Has anyone else experienced this? Is GTM v2 mobile experiments broken?

I have written in the support forum as well but I havn't gotten any replies.

Answer (score 1):

I experienced the same and realised that it only happens when I select a custom goal. When I use one of the predefined goals e.g. "Session Duration" publishing the container works just fine.

Can you confirm that behaviour?

Comment: The problem still exists for me, selection "Session Duration" throws the same error.

Comment: The problem occurs no matter if I choose a predefined goal or custom.